# Kubernetes: Diffrerence between RoleBinding and ClusterRoleBinding

Tags: kubernetes

What is the difference between RoleBinding and ClusterRoleBinding?
And what are the usages of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer the Kubernetes documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole)

> A Role always sets permissions within a particular namespace; when you create a Role, you have to specify the namespace it belongs in.
>
> ClusterRole, by contrast, is a non-namespaced resource. The resources
>   have different names (Role and ClusterRole) because a Kubernetes
>   object always has to be either namespaced or not namespaced; it can’t
>   be both.

Answer (score 7):

A rolebinding is namespace scoped and clusterrolebinding is cluster scoped i.e across all namespace.

ClusterRoles and ClusterRoleBindings are useful in the following cases:

1. Give permissions for non-namespaced resources like nodes
2. Give permissions for resources in all the namespaces of a cluster
3. Give permissions for non-resource endpoints like /healthz

A RoleBinding can also reference a ClusterRole to grant the permissions defined in that ClusterRole to resources inside the RoleBinding's namespace. This kind of reference lets you define a set of common roles across your cluster, then reuse them within multiple namespaces.

Answer (score 3):

The Cluster variants apply to every namespace. The others only to the namespace they are in.